# Building as an Installer instead of EXE

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've inherited a project from a developer who left my company and I'm trying to complete it. It's a vb.net project which we've been writing and compiling in Visual Studio 2010. He created the project and when I build it, it builds an exe file for me to run. What the customer wants is for it to be an installer. Unfortunately, I'm not that well versed in VS so I can't seem to find how to change it so that it builds the installer instead of an executable and it seems like whenever I Google it, I just get tutorials on how to set it up when creating the project.

Long story short, how can I get VS to build an installer instead of an executable in an existing project?

Comment: Added a Setup project, fair warning, the Setup projects were discontinued in more recent versions of Visual Studios, I suggest using one of the alternative methods to create a setup.exe file.

Comment: I can't speak for VS, but Innosetup and NSIS are two different tools you might investigate for building installers.  I typically build installers as a step separate from compiling the .exe.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations (cannot install for all users), but the [click once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx) is a pretty good feature in Visual Studio. This can deploy on a website, local file (CD/DVD ROM) or ftp site. It can also be set to check for updates as well.

This is the Publish Wizard.